# Android phone connected via usb - thumbnails not showing

Tags: permissions, android, thumbnails

Galaxy s1oe phone connected via usb to ubuntu 20.04

Folders show up just fine, I just don't see the thumbnails. It must be a permission thing.

How to fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: it's probably an optimization, and it covers all non-local mounts. but unfortunately, i don't know the answer.